# Angles and Quadrilaterals Problem 70

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle, quadrilateral

In a quadrilateral FGHI, FG = GI, ∠GFI = 70, ∠GHI = 55 and FI is parallel to GH. What is the size of ∠GFH? I thought it would be 50. Is that correct?

Comment: What's your reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got $\measuredangle GFH=35^{\circ}$.

$\measuredangle FIH=180^{\circ}-55^{\circ}=125^{\circ}$ and since $GF=GI$, we obtain $\measuredangle GIH=125^{\circ}-70^{\circ}=55^{\circ}$,

which says $GH=GI=GF$, which gives that $FH$ is a bisector of $\angle GFH$

and from here we obtain: $\measuredangle GFH=35^{\circ}$.

Comment: How did you get GFH = 35? What did you subtract?

Comment: @Valerie $\angle GFH=\angle GHF$ because $GH=GF$. In another hand, $\angle GHF=\angle IFH$. Thus, $\angle GFH=\angle IFH$, which says that  $\measuredangle GFH=\frac{1}{2}\cdot70^{\circ}=35^{\circ}$.